# Cannot connect to clustered AWS Elasticache for Redis

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kotlin, redis

I have created a cluster on AWS Elasticache for Redis. The cluster operates in cluster mode `enabled`. There is 1 shard with 2 nodes currently created.

I'm trying to connect to the cluster through bastion host, thus using such port forwarding:

`LocalForward localhost:6379 my-app.redis.apps.region.company.com:6379`

I can reach the elasticache service with Spring Boot standalone configuration, but when fetching data from the cache, I get `MOVED` exception.
I have tried to switch the configuration to cluster mode using only cluster endpoint, but am getting:

```
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisException: Cannot obtain initial Redis Cluster topology
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.lambda$getPartitions$0(RedisClusterClient.java:329)
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.get(RedisClusterClient.java:941)
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.getPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.ClusterConnectionProvider.getConnectionAsync(ClusterConnectionProvider.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.ClusterConnectionProvider.getConnectionAsync(ClusterConnectionProvider.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionProvider.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1595)
    ... 134 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.DefaultClusterTopologyRefresh$CannotRetrieveClusterPartitions: Cannot retrieve cluster partitions from [redis://clustercfg.redis-*******.****.****.cache.amazonaws.com]
```

Here's my configuration:

```
@Configuration
class RedisConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun connectionFactory(): RedisConnectionFactory? {
        return LettuceConnectionFactory(
            RedisClusterConfiguration().clusterNode(
                "clustercfg.redis-*******.****.****.cache.amazonaws.com",
                6379
            )
        )
    }
    
    @Bean
    fun redisTemplate(redisConnectionFactory: RedisConnectionFactory) =
        RedisTemplate<String, String>().apply {
            setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory)
            StringRedisSerializer().let {
                keySerializer = it
                valueSerializer = it
            }
        }

    @Bean
    fun remoteConfigCacheManager(
        connectionFactory: RedisConnectionFactory
    ): RedisCacheManager? {
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory)
            .withCacheConfiguration(
               “CACHE_NAME”,
                RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(1))
            )
            .build()
    }
}
```

And there's the config in `application.yml`

```
redis:
  host: ${REDIS_HOST:clustercfg.redis-*******.****.****.cache.amazonaws.com}
  port: ${REDIS_PORT:6379}
  password: ${REDIS_PASSWORD:<SOME_SECRET_PASSWORD>}
  ssl: ${REDIS_SSL:true}
```

I've really browsed through every possible SO thread and could not find a solution. Can this be related to my bastion host?

Comment: first, check whether you can access Redis server with a local redis client by using `redis-cli -c` and see if it redirects

Comment: Using that command I get "logged" to `127.0.0.1:6379`. Can use all the commands like `KEYS '*', FLUSHALL` etc.

Comment: yeh i mean try adding keys like 'a','t','x' and then try to retrieve them. if you are getting moved again even with the `-c` option ,check the configurations of elasticache

Comment: were you able to figure this out?